# How to copy data from 1 table to another with different structure

Tags: mysql, database-migration, insert-update

I have a table with the structure

```
CREATE TABLE `old_reminder` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `applicant_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('payment_15_min','payment_1_day','payment_3_day') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'payment_15_min',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

and I want to migrate its data to another table with the structure

```
CREATE TABLE `new_reminders` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_reminder_1_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_reminder_1_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

basically multiple rows for each `user_id` will be converted into 1 row with all the enum values as columns.
I have tried the following but it is updating only 1 row

```
UPDATE reminders 
    INNER JOIN old_reminder AS `old`
    ON user_id = old.applicant_id
    SET new_reminder_1_date = IF(old.type = 'payment_15_min' OR old.type = 'payment_1_day' OR old.type = 'payment_3_day', old.date, '2018-01-01 00:00:00'),
    payment_reminder_1_count = IF(old.type = 'payment_15_min' OR old.type = 'payment_1_day' OR old.type = 'payment_3_day',
    CASE
    WHEN old.type = 'payment_15_min' THEN 1
    WHEN old.type = 'payment_1_day' THEN payment_reminder_1_count + 1
    WHEN old.type = 'payment_3_day' THEN payment_reminder_1_count + 1 END, 0)
    WHERE applicant_id = 123;
```

Comment: I'm suggesting to you to  write a simple migration script using php, python, perl (whatever you are familiar with)

you can fetch required rows from old table and apply necessary changes to the data set and save into the new table.

Comment: I don't think you gave a reproducible/answerable question here.  Can you make it more minimal?

Answer (score 0):

If you model looks like this

```
truncate table old_reminder;
insert into old_reminder (applicant_id,date,type) values (123,'2018-01-01','payment_15_min');
insert into old_reminder (applicant_id,date,type) values (123,'2018-01-02','payment_1_day');
truncate table new_reminders;
insert into new_reminders(user_id,payment_reminder_1_date) values (123,'2016-01-01');
```

Then a simplified version of your query

```
update new_reminders n join (select * from old_reminder order by applicant_id,`date`) old on old.applicant_id = n.user_id
     SET 
     enumstr = old.type,
     payment_reminder_1_date = 
     case 
        when old.type in ('payment_15_min','payment_1_day','payment_3_day') then old.date
        else '2017-01-01'   
     end     
    WHERE applicant_id = 123;
```

Produces this result which I think is what you mean by *it is updating only 1 row*

```
+----+---------+--------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
| id | user_id | payment_reminder_1_count | payment_reminder_1_date | enumstr        |
+----+---------+--------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
|  1 |     123 |                     NULL | 2018-01-01 00:00:00     | payment_15_min |
+----+---------+--------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The where clause is evaluated last in this query and is free to choose which one it wants from the result set - in this case always the first.

if the query is changed to test test the payment_reminder_1_date

```
update new_reminders n join (select * from old_reminder order by applicant_id,`date`) old on old.applicant_id = n.user_id
     SET 
     enumstr = old.type,
     payment_reminder_1_date = 
     case 
        when old.type in ('payment_15_min','payment_1_day','payment_3_day') then old.date
        else '2017-01-01'   
     end     
    WHERE applicant_id = 123 and n.payment_reminder_1_date <> old.`date`
```

Then you get something more like what you hope for

```
+----+---------+--------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
| id | user_id | payment_reminder_1_count | payment_reminder_1_date | enumstr       |
+----+---------+--------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
|  1 |     123 |                     NULL | 2018-01-02 00:00:00     | payment_1_day |
+----+---------+--------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But I don't think this is actually what you are looking for and I would suggest a cursor might be the way forward.